# How to adapt Contents header to match other chapter headers

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, titletoc

I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
```

and customized my headers using

```
\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

The result is the chapter number, a vertical line and the chapter name.

However, the "Contents" header remains untouched. I would like it to look the same as other headers (optionally with a leading 0 (zero)).

The [titlesec](http://mirror.selfnet.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) doc references the package titletoc, which apparently can modify the chapter listings in the contents, but not the content header itself.

How can I accomplish a consistent layout?

Comment: Table of contents makes use o `chapter*` so it is not affected by your `chapter` format.

Comment: How can the general header style be applied to the content header?

Comment: I don't use `titlesec` so check if you can format the starred version `chapter*`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the 'Extended Settings' of the [titlesec doc](http://mirror.selfnet.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf). Thanks to @Sigur for the tip in the comments.

```
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}
```

Mind the `name=`, it seems not to be necessary for the numbered version, but for the unnumbered it apparently is.

Comment: Do you really want “0 – Contents”?

Comment: yes it is, please check the question: "optionally with a leading 0 (zero)"

Comment: If you're happy with it. ;-)